# Unable to navigate to the given URL in Safari using web driver in windows 32-bit

Tags: java, selenium, safari, webdriver

When I'm trying to run a simple test on safari,the browser is getting invoked but the URL of the application given in the test is not getting launched.

```
OS- Windows 7 32-bit
Safari 5.1.7
selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0
```

I'm getting the following on the Safari window:
SafariDriver Client

```
[  0.098s] [safaridriver.client] Requesting connection at ws://localhost:39381...
[  0.169s] [safaridriver.client] Request acknowledged; connecting...
```

and nothing is happening after this.

The following is displayed on the console:

```
May 1, 2014 2:35:59 PM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverServer start
INFO: Server started on port 39381
May 1, 2014 2:35:59 PM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor start
INFO: Launching Safari
May 1, 2014 2:35:59 PM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor start
INFO: Waiting for SafariDriver to connect
May 1, 2014 2:36:44 PM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor stop
INFO: Shutting down
May 1, 2014 2:36:44 PM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor stop
INFO: Stopping Safari
May 1, 2014 2:36:44 PM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverChannelHandler exceptionCaught
WARNING: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:59)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.processSelectedKeys(AbstractNioWorker.java:465)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:332)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:35)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
May 1, 2014 2:36:44 PM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor stop
INFO: Stopping server
May 1, 2014 2:36:44 PM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverServer stop
INFO: Stopping server
May 1, 2014 2:36:44 PM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor stop
INFO: Uninstalling extensions
May 1, 2014 2:36:44 PM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor stop
INFO: Shutdown complete
May 1, 2014 2:36:44 PM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor stop
INFO: Shutting down
May 1, 2014 2:36:44 PM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor stop
INFO: Stopping server
May 1, 2014 2:36:44 PM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor stop
INFO: Uninstalling extensions
May 1, 2014 2:36:44 PM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor stop
INFO: Shutdown complete
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Failed to connect to SafariDriver after 45118 ms
Build info: version: '2.41.0', revision: '3192d8a', time: '2014-03-27 17:17:32'
System info: host: 'C5609E1D', ip: '172.24.161.46', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_33'
Driver info: driver.version: SafariDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor.start(SafariDriverCommandExecutor.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver.startClient(SafariDriver.java:72)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:114)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:139)
    at org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver.<init>(SafariDriver.java:58)
    at org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver.<init>(SafariDriver.java:42)
    at SafariTest.main(SafariTest.java:9)
```

Could anyone please provide us with a solution for this.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Do you have anything like the following in your code?

```
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(waitForPageToLoad, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

If yes then remove it and try again. I had the same issue and it was resolved after I read the following https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=6015